Adding template file in yaml file for Azure pipeline
I am trying to reference a template file from my current yaml file but while validating the template it is not able to find the referenced template.
The folder structure looks something like this:
Inside IAC folder there are two folders Deploy and Operations. Inside these two folders are the respective yaml files. Inside Deploy -> Optimization.yaml and inside Operations -> Backup.yaml
/IAC
  /Deploy
    Optimization.yaml
  /Operations
    Backup.yaml

Everything is inside a repository SPECS.
This is how my main yaml file looks like.
In the last line where I am referencing template, if i give it as -> ../Deploy/Operations.yaml it will work, but is there any other way to reference it from source directory by specifying the actual path ? I don't want to reference it like this ../
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: App
    type: git
    name: App
    ref: main

schedules:
- cron: '0 8 2-30/2 * *'
  displayName: Run on every alternate days 8 AM UTC
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
    exclude:
      - feature/*
  paths:
   include:
     - IAC/Operations/Backup.yaml
    
stages:
  - stage: Backup
    jobs:
      - job: Job

        pool: ‘XYZ’
  
        steps:
          - checkout: App
          - checkout: self
          
          - task: AzureKeyVault@2
            displayName: Retrive credentials from Azure Kayvault

          - template: IAC/Deploy/Optimization.yaml        

When using this line
 - template: IAC/Deploy/Optimization.yaml   

I get error as:


/IAC/Operations/Backup.yaml: File /IAC/Operations/IAC/Deploy/Optimization.yaml not found in repository.


For some reason it is going inside Operations folder and searching the Optimization.yaml file which shouldn't be the case.
When I use
- template: ../Deploy/Optimization.yaml   

In this case it is able to reference the correct file and the pipeline is able to run.
Is there any way to reference the Optimization.yaml file without using the operator ../ and by directly giving the path to the file itself?

Why does it matter how you specify the path as long as it can locate the template file?

Did the answer below help?


When using this line
 - template: IAC/Deploy/Optimization.yaml    

I get error as:


/IAC/Operations/Backup.yaml: File /IAC/Operations/IAC/Deploy/Optimization.yaml not found in repository.



For some reason it's searching for the template inside folder /IAC/Operations.
I'd suggest using absolute paths to reference remplates to avoid similar issues:
- template: /IAC/Deploy/Optimization.yaml

Using absolute paths has the added advantage of ensuring that the template references are always resolved correctly when moving pipelines or templates to different folders, without the need to update the paths.
You may also use @self to refer to a template in the current repository:
- template: /path/to/my/template.yaml@self

